# Massage Smarty array in PHP andsend it back to Smarty . . .?

Tags: php, smarty

**How would you a) fix a Smarty array in PHP and b) stick the result back into the Smarty array variable?**

Have you ever worked on a problem, and you thought you were SO close to resolving it, but the target keeps on slipping farther and farther away? I spent half a day on this, looking up documentation, searching for examples...but I must be missing something very basic.

**Premise:** I have a Smarty array with duplicate entries (and for now I cannot change the way this gets created, because the Smarty code is encoded in a template). This causes problems, because now I get multiple entries for the same product in the shopping cart. RIGHT NOW, I honestly cannot change the logic of how this was put together.

Here's what I got:

```
Smarty:
         {$products}
```

In my scenario, {$products} contains four entries like so:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(12) { ["pid"]=> string(2) "13" ["domain"]=> NULL
["billingcycle"]=> string(4) "free" ["configoptions"]=> string(0) "" 
["customfields"]=> array(0) { } ["addons"]=> array(0) { } ["server"]=> string(0) ""
["productinfo"]=> array(9) { ["pid"]=> string(2) "13" ["gid"]=> string(1) "2" 
["type"]=> string(5) "other" ["groupname"]=> string(13) "Beta Products" ["name"]=>
string(44) "BetterStuff "Free Until 2014" Beta" ["description"]=> string(21) 
"BetterStuff installer" ["freedomain"]=> string(0) "" ["freedomainpaymentterms"]=> 
array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["freedomaintlds"]=> array(1) {[0]=> string(0) ""}}
["allowqty"]=> string(1) "0" ["qty"]=> int(1) ["pricing"]=> array(4) { ["baseprice"]=>
string(9) "$0.00 USD" ["setup"]=> string(9) "$0.00 USD" ["recurring"]=> array(0){}
["totaltoday"]=> string(9) "$0.00 USD" } ["pricingtext"]=> string(5) "FREE!" } }
```

In PHP, I can easily use array-unique, to get rid of the 3 exact copies within this array, and be left with just one (as the one I just showed above).

```
{php}
    $var = $this->get_template_vars('products');
    $var = array_unique($var);
    $smarty = new Smarty();
    $smarty->assign('newproducts', $var = array_unique($var));
    var_dump($var);
{/php}
```

This works perfectly, in PHP, and the var_dump($var) contains one array item (just like the one I showed above). In PHP, when I check $var with is_array, the result is true.

Back in Smarty, however, {$newproducts} is NULL.

- When I try to re-assign the original Smarty array {$products}, I get
  an error message about not being allowed to add string values to the
  array.
- When I try to print out {$newproducts|@count}, I get 0. That's
  slight;y confusing to me, because I believe that Smart arrays start
  at 1, whereas PHP arrays are zero-based.
- So although PHP considers the variable I assign to be the value for
  the new variable an array, it doesn't come into Smarty as an array.

**What am I doing wrong here?** Do I need to explode or split my PHP array somehow, so that I can turn it into a Smarty variable?

And how can I "reset" the original {$products} array in Smarty to the new unique array value?

Anyone?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong but doesn't this simple work ? `{$products|array_unique}`

Comment: Hmmm, that doesn't do anything, in terms of "cleaning up" the array with duplicate/triplicate identical items. Thank you very much for taking the time though.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no real answer and I was stuck with the same problem, that is, not being able to call array_unique from the php side since I had no access to the code generating it.

Here is the code that worked for me in Smarty:

```
    {foreach from=$items item=item}
        {if !in_array($item, $array)} 
            <li>{$item}</li>
            {append var='array' value=$item}                       
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
```

It makes use of the smarty [**append**](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.append.tpl) command, which will add items to an array. Furthermore I made use of [**in_array**](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.tpl) (scroll down to the bullet regarding *php_functions*) which is, among some other php functions available in Smarty.

I hope this might help someone else out!

Answer (score 0):

```
{php}
    // read data from CURRENT INSTANCE
    $var = $this->get_template_vars('products');
    $var = array_unique($var);
    // create NEW INSTANCE
    $smarty = new Smarty();
    // assign to NEW INSTANCE
    $smarty->assign('newproducts', $var = array_unique($var));
    var_dump($var);
{/php}
```

so, you're creating a new smarty instance and assigning data to it. Is there a reason you believe said data would be available in the *current* instance?

try this:

```
{php}
    // read data from CURRENT INSTANCE
    $var = $this->get_template_vars('products');
    $var = array_unique($var);
    // assign to CURRENT INSTANCE
    $this->assign('newproducts', $var = array_unique($var));
{/php}
```

And {php} is deprecated. You might want to look into [Extending Smarty With Plugins](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/plugins.tpl)

Comment: Hey thanks for that. To answer your question, no, I did not have any reasons to believe that the CURRENT INSTANCE would get updated . . . that's why I went with the NEW INSTANCE approach. The idea was then to let Smarty take the new variable (newproducts) and replace the contents of the OLD/CURRENT variable (products) accordingly. Just tested your solution, and it results in: Fatal error: Call to a member function assign() on a non-object . . .